# How to concatenate two strings into the third string without copying?

Tags: string, rust, concatenation, move, ownership

I'm new to Rust and I'm currently reading The Rust Programming Language book.

I'm curious about this example:

```
fn main() {
    let s1 = String::from("Hello, ");
    let s2 = String::from("world!");
    let s3 = s1 + &s2; // note s1 has been moved here and can no longer be used
}
```

Is it possible to take ownership not only of `s1`, but also of `s2`, so `s2` gets invalidated as well as `s1`, making `s3` the only possible variable that remains usable?

Comment: Why? Sounds like an X/Y problem.

Comment: @mcarton I was actually more curious about if it's possible to make a string without explicitly copying the contents of one of the strings. Basically, the new string should contain 2 pointers of type String one after another. Now I realized that this should be a custom type, and it's not possible using the default String implementation. It's more of a theoretical question, that asks for language-specific design, that is yet not that well known by me.

Comment: @cr7pt0pl4gu3 no, in order to concatenate the strings there needs to be a single contiguous allocation. But even if they happened to be next to one another in physical memory (which is not likely) `s1` and `s2` are different allocations. So the best you can do in the standard library is append `s2` at the end of `s1`'s buffer.

Comment: Although outside of the standard library there might be a *ropes* lib: *ropes* are pseudo-strings designed as a shallow tree of buffers, the primary goal is to easily update segments of text in-place, without the need to move a lot of data around. But a side-effect is that a rope concatenates two strings by just referencing both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

This is not possible. A `String` has to be a single contiguous allocation in memory. If you want to roll your own simple solution you can probably define a type like this:

```rust
struct MyString {
    parts: Vec<String>,
}

impl MyString {
    fn concat(&mut self, other: String) {
        self.parts.push(other);
    }
}
```

However re-implementing every useful `String` method for this custom type is going to be tedious and error-prone. You can find a Rust crate which implements a [Rope data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(data_structure)), and [an-rope](https://docs.rs/an-rope/0.3.1/an_rope/) seems to be such a crate, but only a tiny fraction of `String` methods are supported.

---

I gave this answer when I interpreted OP's question as one about invalidating and moving variables:

**Original Answer**

You can invalidate any non-`Copy` variable by moving it somewhere else, like by passing it to the `drop` function:

```rust
fn main() {
    let s1 = String::from("Hello, ");
    let s2 = String::from("world!");
    let s3 = s1 + &s2; // s1 invalidated
    drop(s2); // s2 invalidated
    // now only s3 is usable
}
```

If this is a common pattern in your application you can just write a function which takes ownership of 2 `String`s and returns the concatenated result:

```rust
fn concat(s1: String, s2: String) -> String {
    s1 + &s2
}

fn main() {
    let s1 = String::from("Hello, ");
    let s2 = String::from("world!");
    let s3 = concat(s1, s2); // s1 & s2 invalidated
    // now only s3 is usable
}
```

Comment: @cr7pt0pl4gu3 Do note that this does not prevent copying of the second `String`, so disabling its ownership is kind of pointless.